# Relative paths in Windows XP

Tags: windows, path, windows-xp, relative-path, path-separator

I have an application which works perfectly in Mac OS and I want to make it work in Windows XP.

I have a function which returns this one. This is where I declare my folder `My_Home`.

> return "." + File.separator + "My_Home" + File.separator + HomePane.objFile ;

I want to do the same thing in Windows. I have tried:

> return File.separator + "My_Home" + File.separator + HomePane.objFile ;
>
> return "My_Home" + File.separator + HomePane.objFile ;
>
> ".\My_Home\" HomePane.objFile ;
>
> "\My_Home\" HomePane.objFile ;
>
> "My_Home\" HomePane.objFile ;
>
> "./My_Home/" HomePane.objFile ;

etc. with \, but nothing seems to work in Windows, because all the objects (I want to use this return in order to save some objects in folder `My_Home`) are saved outside of the folder.

What can I do?

Comment: All of your paths (well, not the second one) are relative to the current directory. You neglected to mention what the current directory is when you run your program, or what the desired absolute path to `My_Home` is.

Comment: Well, I do that in eclipse, so my current directory is c:/ME/Workspace/MYPROJECT and there I want to place My_Home

Comment: Have you confirmed via `GetCurrentDirectory` that your current directory really is `C:\ME\Workspace\MYPROJECT`? Presumably you want the file to be `C:\ME\Workspace\MYPROJECT\My_Home\objFile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "My_Home" + File.separator + HomePane.objFile

was right, the problem was mine. Thank you all:)